# How to represent a linear solution as an affine solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I have gotten the following general solution for some system

$Ax=w$

Therefore our general solution is $x=\begin{pmatrix}3\\
1-\gamma\\
3+\gamma\\
\gamma
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\
1\\
3\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\gamma\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$

I understand that an affine space is a linear space + some sort of offset from the origin. Isn't this exactly what I already have? How would I find the affine map for this solution set?

Comment: You are right. You have already written the solution as an offset + "a linear space". The only thing you could change would be to write $$x \in \begin{pmatrix} 3\\1\\3\\0 \end{pmatrix}+ \text{span}(\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix})$$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. In general you can express an affine subspace $\Lambda$ as
$$\Lambda\equiv P_0+W=P_0+\text{dir}(\Lambda),$$
where $P_0$ is a point and $W$ is the vector space associated to your affine subspace $\Lambda$, so $W$ contains the linear combinations of the vectors that generate $\Lambda$ (and its "direction")  and it determines its dimension.
In your example, the affine subspace is a line in $\mathbb R^4$, since $\text{dim}(W)=\text{dim}(\Big\langle\begin{pmatrix} 0\\-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} \Big\rangle)=1$.